# ScrollView with Button Below Scrolls Different Inside TabHost

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-tabhost

I have an Activity that consists of a large scrollview (that contains EditText fields) along with a button that is anchored to the bottom of the screen (not part of the scrollView). This is a simple example to display the issue I am seeing. The manifest for my app specifies android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustPan for all Activities.

If I run this Activity directly, everything is displayed correctly and the scrollview scrolls between the edit fields as it should.

I don't have enough points to post images or >2 hyperlinks.....

[No TabHost - edit first field](http://www.mindspring.com/~dscavo/stackoverflow/notabhost_edit_first_field.png)

If I run this Activity as the content of a TabHost, the scrolling seems to be borked. Whenever an EditText gains focus, the activity properly pans to the Edit field. However, it also forces the button onto the screen.

[Inside TabHost - edit first field - Where did that button come from](http://www.mindspring.com/~dscavo/stackoverflow/tabhost_edit_first_field.png)

I have tried creating the layout for this Activity using a LinearLayout (with negative margin for the button) as well as a RelativeLayout, and both exhibit the same issue with the button always being visible when scrolling through the 3 EditText fields.

Has anyone seen anything like this before or have any idea how to get the scrolling to work properly inside the TabHost ?????

LinearLayout version

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >       
        <EditText android:id="@+id/e1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:hint="edit text 1"
            />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/e2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:hint="edit text 2"
            />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/e3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:hint="edit text 3"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_marginTop="-60dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

RelativeLayout Version

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >       
        <EditText android:id="@+id/e1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:hint="edit text 1"
            />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/e2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:hint="edit text 2"
            />
        <EditText android:id="@+id/e3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:hint="edit text 3"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps someone else.....

All the Activities that were hosted inside the TabHost had android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustPan.

However, the Activity that hosted the TabHost was missing android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustPan.
Once I added that, the panning worked the smae inside a TabHost or outside the TabHost.